# Need help regarding CSV which generated by linux script

Tags: excel, datetime, csv

I have generated a data from a text using shell script in solaris. Data is like below.

```
2015-01-06 00:00:00 588,1945818677,BD9010600000007,200,Transaction Successful,1200,PRETOP
2015-01-06 00:00:00 592,1945816793,BD9010600000005,200,Transaction Successful,2000,PRETOP
2015-01-06 00:00:00 615,1945818682,BD9010600000006,200,Transaction Successful,2500,PRETOP
2015-01-06 00:00:01 184,1945818661,BD9010600000013,200,Transaction Successful,4000,PRETOP
```

Here date time is not showing properly when i am trying to open it in excell. also there is no option to format the excell column. How can i fix it.

Comment: On importing, use the delimited mode, select comma as the delimiter, and in the 3rd step of the text import wizard, select the date column and pick the format YMD (assuming it's in year-month-date)

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file normally (via File-Open), some non-US Excel versions will assume semicolons as field separators. To work around that, import the file instead of opening it (it depends on the Office version how you'd do this). Then the import wizard will allow you to choose the appropriate delimiter.

In Excel 2013, you can invoke that wizard via the DATA tab; I don't know if that has changed from Excel 2010 - see this screenshot from the German Excel version:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Sometimes it also works if you open the file by double-clicking it in Explorer - try to see which solution is applicable for you.

Comment: Which Excel version are you using? How are you opening the file?

Comment: i am using 2010 version... i have first open a blank excel and then open the file in it using comma as deliminator